# How can I get all <a> elements with a class name in PHP using xpath and add a <p> tag under each of those elements?

Tags: php, xpath

I tried to use xpath to get all a elements with the class name 'post-title' in PHP, but it's not working. **I should mention that the a elements are being outputted by a shortcode, so I'm not even sure if xpath would work in this scenario.** I'm not sure why but it's returning a DOMNodeList object of length 0 in $items. I also want to get the post_title which is the text within the a element so I'm using $post_title = $item->nodeValue, but I'm not sure if that would work. Any help would be most appreciated.

```
    function add_rating_below_search_result_post_title(){
        $dom = new DomDocument;
        $dom->loadHTMLFile("example.com");
        $xpath = new DomXPath($dom);    
        $items = $xpath->query("//a[@class='post-title']");
    
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $post_title = $item->nodeValue;
            $post_id = get_page_by_title($post_title, OBJECT, 'post');
            
            $rating_content = get_rating($post_id);
            
            $doc = new DOMDocument();
            $rating = $doc->createElement("p", $rating_content);
          
            $item->appendChild($rating);        
        }
    }
```

This is the sample HTML for one item. There are multiple items like this in the HTML. The a element I want is on the 6th line from the bottom. I need to get all a elements that match this pattern for each of the items.

```
<div class="cl-layout__item cl-layout__item--id-1234">
<div class="cl-layout__item-spacing">
<div class="cl-template cl-template--post cl-template--id-1234 cl-template--image-top">
<div class="cl-element cl-element-featured_media cl-element--instance-1234  cl-element-featured_media--sizing-natural">
<a class="cl-element-featured_media__anchor" href="https://www.example.com/item1/"><img data-pin-title="Item Search" class="cl-element-featured_media__image" src="https://cdn.shortpixel.ai/spai/w_300+q_lossless+ret_img+to_webp/https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Item1-300x300.jpg" data-spai="1" alt="Item 1" data-pin-nopin="true" data-spai-upd="339">
<noscript data-spai="1"><img data-pin-title="Item Search"  class="cl-element-featured_media__image"  src="https://cdn.shortpixel.ai/spai/q_lossless+ret_img/https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Item1-300x300.jpg" data-spai-egr="1"  alt="Item 1"  />
</noscript>
</a>
</div>
<div class="cl-element cl-element-section cl-element--instance-1222 ">
<h4 class="cl-element cl-element-title cl-element--instance-1333 ">
<a class="post-title" href="https://www.example.com/item1/">Item 1 post title</a>
</h4>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is the DOM being correctly loaded with `$dom->loadHTMLFile("example.com");`??? For a remote url the scheme would be required to the best of my knowledge

Comment: Yes, the HTML  file loaded correctly as the result was true indicating success. I had to use example.com in my code as StackOverflow forbids the use of http/https urls in code.

Comment: erm - that's a new one on me... afaik there is no such restriction on using the scheme within a string url here.

Comment: Add a sample of the html please.

Comment: I've added a sample of the HTML in the question.

Comment: The most likely thing is that the content is being generated by Javascript. Perhaps sharing the actual url would help

Answer (score 0):

If you run the following "as-is" first you ought to see a representation of the modified document in the textarea and then, if you enable the second URL and run it ( without scheme ) there is an issue.

This is substantially the same as your code - without seeing the proper url it is hard to say where the issue lies as you have two undeclared and unknown methods `get_page_by_title` and `get_rating`

There is, as you can see from the below code, no need to invoke a new DOMDocument object in the `foreach` loop to simply add a new node

```
<?php
    $url='https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php';
    #$url='php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php';
    
    
    libxml_use_internal_errors( true );
    $dom=new DOMDocument;
    $dom->validateOnParse=false;
    $dom->recover=true;
    $dom->strictErrorChecking=false;
    $dom->loadHTMLFile( $url );
    libxml_clear_errors();
    
    
    $xp=new DOMXPath( $dom );
    $expr='//a[@class="methodname"]';
    
    $col=$xp->query( $expr );
    if( $col->length > 0 ){
        foreach( $col as $node ){
            $linktext=$node->nodeValue;
            $p=$dom->createElement('p','------BANANA BANANA BANANA-------');
            $node->appendChild($p);
        }
        
        printf('<textarea cols=100 rows=20>%s</textarea>',$dom->saveHTML() );
    }
?>
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work, and I think I just realized why. The a elements that I want to get are being outputted by a shortcode on the page so maybe xpath won't work for me at all. I've updated the question.